# How to use dexterity/forms to add a list of custom objects?

Tags: plone, python-datetime, dexterity

I create a class IAgenda and set value_type=schema.Datetime() and it works. I can add a list of datetimes in my agenda object

```
class IAgenda(model.Schema):    
    dates = schema.List(
        title=_(u"label_dates", default=u"Dates"),
        description=_(u"help_dates", default=u"Enter dates"),
        value_type=schema.Datetime(),
        required=True,
    )
```

But when I tried to use a class IInterval on dates I got an error on save: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'year'.

```
class IInterval(Interface):
    start = schema.Datetime(
        title=_(u"label_start", default=u"Start"),
        description=_(u"help_start", default=u"Enter a start date"),
        required=True,
    )

    end = schema.Datetime(
        title=_(u"label_end", default=u"End"),
        description=_(u"help_end", default=u"Enter an end date"),
        required=True,
    )


class IAgenda(model.Schema):
    dates = schema.List(
        title=_(u"label_dates", default=u"Dates"),
        description=_(u"help_dates", default=u"Enter dates"),
        value_type=schema.Object(IInterval),
        required=True,
    )
```

If I change start and end fields to Int I got another error: "The system could not process the given value".
So, what is the correct way to use dexterity/forms to add a list of custom objects?

Comment: You may have better luck posting Plone questions in https://community.plone.org (more eyeballs)

Comment: @T.KimNguyen Thanks, I will post.

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried specifying your value_type from schema.Object with zope.schema.Object(__name__='interval', title=label, schema=IInterval, required=True), as in https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/forms/z3c.form.html#combined-widgets?